# Fast and reliable technique to modify a buffer's bytes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I wish to read the contents of a binary file, perform a binary NOT on every byte in the files buffer and then write the modified buffer back to another file on disk. I currently use something like the following:

```
data = nil

::File.open( 'somefile.bin', 'rb' ) do | f |
    data = f.read( f.stat.size )
end

# unpack can sometimes throw an out of memory exception
raw_bytes = data.unpack( 'C*' )

raw_bytes.map! do | byte |
    ~byte
end

::File.open( 'somefile.bin.not', 'wb' ) do | f |
    f.write( raw_bytes.pack( 'C*' ) )
end
```

This works, however unpack sometimes throws an out of memory exception. Is it possible to edit the `data` buffer directly without resorting to having to unpack it to an array (I chose to do this so I could use map! to modify the bytes).

As this needs to be performed on 100s of thousands of files (all files are <= 30MB in size) performance is important. The above solution is performing ok but is not reliable due to the out of memory issue. I believe avoiding the unpack and modifying the data buffer directly might avoid this.

Can anybody improve on my existing solution? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe avoiding the unpack and modifying the data buffer directly might avoid this.

Your data buffer is a binary string, i.e. a sequence of characters in the range 0x00 to 0xFF. You can flip the character's bits by mapping them to the reversed range 0xFF to 0x00:

```
0x00 (00000000) -> 0xFF (11111111)
0x01 (00000001) -> 0xFE (11111110)
0x02 (00000010) -> 0xFD (11111101)
0x03 (00000011) -> 0xFC (11111100)
...
0x7E (01111110) -> 0x81 (10000001)
0x7F (01111111) -> 0x80 (10000000)
0x80 (10000000) -> 0x7F (01111111)
0x81 (10000001) -> 0x7E (01111110)
...
0xFC (11111100) -> 0x03 (00000011)
0xFD (11111101) -> 0x02 (00000010)
0xFE (11111110) -> 0x01 (00000001)
0xFF (11111111) -> 0x00 (00000000)
```

The fastest way to apply a character-to-character mapping is probably [`String#tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-tr). You simply pass two strings `a` and `b`, and `tr` replaces all characters from `a` with the corresponding characters in `b`.

```
a = (0..255).map(&:chr).join #=> "\x00\x01\x02...\xFD\xFE\xFF"
b = a.reverse                #=> "\xFF\xFE\xFD...\x02\x01\x00"
```

Because `"-"` and `"\\"` have a special meaning in `tr`, they have to be escaped:

```
a.gsub!(/[\\-]/, '\\\\\0')
b.gsub!(/[\\-]/, '\\\\\0')
```

Let's see how this performs:

```
require 'benchmark'

@data = IO.read('/dev/random', 30_000_000)

@a = (0..255).map(&:chr).join
@b = @a.reverse

@a.gsub!(/[\\-]/, '\\\\\0')
@b.gsub!(/[\\-]/, '\\\\\0')

Benchmark.bm(5) do |x|
  x.report("pack:") { @data.unpack('C*').map(&:~).pack('C*') }
  x.report("tr:")   { @data.tr(@a, @b) }
end
```

Results:

```
            user     system      total        real
pack:   4.780000   0.150000   4.930000 (  5.082274)
tr:     0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.078761)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to read 1mb each time around, instead of storing everything into memory. In the tests I did none of the versions crashed, so I can't be sure this one won't crash, but there is a good chance it won't. As a bonus, I also managed to get a modest 5% performance increase (don't ask me how xD), according with the tests I performed. Here it is:

```
File.open( 'somefile.bin', 'rb' ) do | file |
    File.open( 'somefile.bin.not', 'wb' ) do | out |
        until file.eof?
            buffer = file.read( 1024*1024 ).unpack( 'C*' ).map do | byte |
                ~byte
            end

            out.write( buffer.pack( 'C*' ) )
        end
    end
end
```

It would be nice if you could test it in your environment and tell me how it turned out afterwards.